# spree ecommerce set minimum order amount for cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, spree

We want to define a minimum order value. If line items total less than $500, it will show up error message when customer click on "checkout" button. Can we be able to find this setting under config for admin account?

Comment: I think we're going to need a lot more detail about the structure of your app...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like spree doesn't have the minimum order value as configurable. You need to add some custom code to achieve this. Check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/momolog/7708256) for an example of custom code.